# Cannot read individual characters after running getline

Tags: c, getline

This is a code snippet from getline's manual page , it works perfectly fine.

```
FILE* fp;
size_t len = 0;
char* line = NULL;
ssize_t read;
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

However when I try to access individual characters out of a line variable, for example:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
    printf("%s", line);
    printf("%s", line[0]);
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: *I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.* On what line?  Did you try running in a debugger?  Hint:  check the return values on every function call you make...

Comment: `printf("%s", line[0]);` this line, removing it makes program work again

Comment: I am not sure if `getline` add the proper null terminator at the end. If `line` is not null terminated, `printf("%s",line)` will read past the end of the `line` array, reaching invalid memory and causing an access violation.

Comment: *printf("%s", line[0]); this line, removing it makes program work again* Now there's a clue.  What is `line[0]` anyway?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, he said it already in question :)

Comment: @Saibot Yes, but I'm hoping the reason it's failing will become apparent with a bit of thought, especially given that the preceding `printf()` does work...

Comment: So far, whenever I had a string (whether it was char[] or char* I could always access it's individual characters using indexes such as my_str[0]. Why exactly shouldn't it work here?

Also according to documentation those strings are null-terminated, not like it matters since the error happens when I try to print only the first character, `printf("%s", line);` works fine just like I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Can you try `printf("%s", *line[0]);` instead of `printf("%s", line[0]);`?

Comment: @Pleasebegentle Pay careful attention to the percent operator of printf. The character after the percent sign changes with the data type.

Comment: @rlee827 So it is about string formatting a char?

Comment: `printf("%s", line[0]);` will generate a warning with a good compiler with warnings enabled.  Save time.  Enable your compiler warnings.  That feedback is much faster than posting SO.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
printf("%s", line[0]);
```

is not how to print a character. `%s` tells `printf()` to expect a string which in C is char array (which is equivalent to a pointer to char). So the char gets treated as the address of a string which causes segmentation fault.

This is what you wanted to do:

```
printf("%c", line[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I guess working mostly with languages where character is just string of len 1 dumbed down my thinking. Also the error messages being cryptical in C.